# Is Protractor 5 Compatible with Selenium 2.53?

Tags: selenium, protractor, webdriver-manager

I know that protractor 5 comes with Selenium webdriver-manager 3.x.  However is it safe to connect to a 2.x webdriver-manager or do I have to use 3.x?

Comment: Any reason behind trying to use latest protractor with older selenium version?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. In Protractor 5, we needed to update the selenium-webdriver node dependency from 3.x. In order to have this to run, we also needed to upgrade the selenium standalone server jar file to 3.x. Also there are significant changes from Protractor 5 for the selenium-webdriver 3.x upgrade. See [the commit](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/a3e8b4319d3e8b049e55e5c3c64a7fdb5a132ddf).